# how to inject Mockito service layer in clientside interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit4, junit5

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private TwinApiUserClient userClient; //client side interface we get the data through some queries
    public TwinCollectionUserResponse getUserIds() {
        return userClient.query(UUID.fromString("s8yt544-sadsa4-sda-dfds-hfdsfsjfs8"), null, null).getBody();
    }
```

UserSerivceTest.class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserSerivceTest{

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl UserService;

    @MockBean
    private TwinApiUserClient userClient;

    @Test
    public void testGetTwins() {
        TwinUsernResponse userResponse = this.getTwinUserResponse();//here userResponse is hard coded
        Mockito.when(userClient.query(UUID.fromString("s8yt544-sadsa4-sda-dfds-hfdsfsjfs8"), null, null).getBody()).thenReturn(userResponse);
        assertThat(UserService.getUserIds()).isEqualTo(userResponse);
    }
```

but I am getting a null pointer exception. when trying to initialize the TwinApiUserClient Interface through Mockito hardcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) docs which allow you to use [Mockito deep stubs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/index.html?org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html)

```java
    @MockBean(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private TwinApiUserClient userClient;
```

This allows you to mock the result of a chain of calls like `a().b().c()` which is what you have attempted here.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Mockito.when(userClient.query(UUID.fromString("s8yt544-sadsa4-sda-dfds-hfdsfsjfs8"), null, null).getBody()).thenReturn(userResponse);
```

I think, your problem in `.getBody()` part. When you setup your mocks you should write expected method call and expected result. So, expected method call is `.query()` method and expected result, I guess,  is `userResponse`.